# recommended way to download images in python requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I see that there are two ways to download images using python-reuqests.

1. Uisng PIL as stated in docs (https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content):

   ```
   from PIL import Image
   from io import BytesIO
   i = Image.open(BytesIO(r.content))
   ```
2. using streamed response content:

   ```
   r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
   with open(image_name, 'wb') as f:
       for chunk in r.iter_content():
           f.write(chunk)
   ```

Which is the recommended wya to download images however? both have its merits I suyppose, and I was wondering what is the optimal approach.

Comment: what is `r.content` in the first option?

Comment: @balderman I presume this is [`requests.content`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content)

Comment: @AndrejKesely I think so as well.. so what is the point to use PIL and requests if all you want to do is to save image to the disk?

Comment: @balderman If you want to save just to disk, there's no point to go through PIL, just `f.write()` it to disk. Like an answer below.

Comment: I agree - I can see the added value of using PIL

Comment: @balderman you mean you see *no* added value of using PIL?

Comment: I asked the question because it it mentioned in the requests doc as the way to do it: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content

Comment: @AJW Yes - I missed the NO ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I love the minimalist way. There is nothing called **right way**. It depends on the task you want to perform and the constraints you have.

```py
import requests

with open('file.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(requests.get(url).content)
# if you change png to jpg, there will be no error
```

Answer (score 0):

I did use the below lines of code in a function to save images.

```
    # import the required libraries from Python
    import pathlib,urllib.request,os,uuid
    
    # URL of the image you want to download
    image_url = "https://example.com/image.png"

    # Using the uuid generate new and unique names for your images
    filename = str(uuid.uuid4())

    # Strip the image extension from it's original name
    file_ext = pathlib.Path(image_url).suffix
    
    # Join the new image name to the extension
    picture_filename = filename + file_ext

    # Using pathlib, specify where the image is to be saved
    downloads_path = str(pathlib.Path.home() / "Downloads")

    # Form a full image path by joining the path to the 
    # images' new name
    picture_path  = os.path.join(downloads_path, picture_filename)

    # Using "urlretrieve()" from urllib.request save the image
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_url, picture_path)

    # urlretrieve() takes in 2 arguments
    # 1. The URL of the image to be downloaded
    # 2. The image new name after download. By default, the image is 
    #    saved inside your current working directory
```